# LocalStorage stream not finishing?

Tags: flutter, dart, stream

I'm using the LocalStorage package and need to get a list of all my keys. Looking at the API, it looks like I use the stream field for this, so I coded

```
final subscription =
    _localStorage.stream.listen((Map<String, dynamic> data) {
  print('data: ${data.keys}');
}, onDone: () {
  print('Done!');
});
```

This works fine for loading the keys, but onDone is never triggered? I'm new to streams, so likely missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onDone` callback of the [listen](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Stream/listen.html) method will be executed when the listened stream is closed and the "done" event is sent.

In your case it should happen when you call `_localStorage.dispose();` and the local storage will notify its listener that no more events will be produced.

Until that the stream will be open and the listener will be waiting for new events.